# MICROSOFT EXCEL Change column value based on other column

Tags: excel

I need a small help in Excel, I have two columns say C and D I need to change column C values from Andhra Pradesh to Telangana when D column value is Warangal.

Eg:      C
   1.Andhra Pradesh
   2.Andhra Pradesh
   3.Karnataka

```
   D <br>
```

1.Warangal
   2.Krishna
   3.Bangalore

From above example C, D columns first(1) value is Andhra Pradesh and Warangal, so I want to change C column Value to Telangana. There were many such combinations. I want changes for whole C column. Hope you understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be solved by simply having the following formula in Column E, cell E1, dragged down:

```
=IF(AND(C1="Andhra Pradesh",D1="Warangal"),"Telangana",C1)
```

This preserves the original value of C1, and puts it in E1, unless C1 = Andhra Pradesh while D1 = Warangal. If that is the case, it inserts "Telangana" instead.

Then either use column E in your formulas instead of C (you can hide column C if you like), or copy the values in column E to column C.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(D1 = "Warangal", "Telangana", "Andhra Pradesh")
```